# How do I control the textbox border of an invalid pattern on IE11?

Tags: html, css

This is how it looks like in IE: [image: IE11]

I tried using this method below but it only works partially.  Meaning, if I would to type the invalid pattern the border is fixed to 2px and when I click anywhere outside the textbox it revert back to that thick line.

```
#openSeason [type=text]:invalid 
{ 
    border: 2px red solid;
}
```

However, it does work on Firefox and Chrome. This is how it looks like in Firefox and how I want it to look like in IE11 too:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `outline:none;`

```
#openSeason [type=text]:invalid 
{ 
   border: 2px red solid;
   outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what do you want but maybe this is your answer:

please see this code

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kermani/sC3F6/)

```
     #openSeason[type=text] {
   border: 2px solid;
    border-color:black silver silver black;
   }

#openSeason[type=text]:hover, #openSeason[type=text]:focus{

   border:2px solid green;
}

#openSeason[type=text]:invalid{
    border:2px solid red;
}
```